# Partial template specialization may not work for functions, but isn't overloading the same thing?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, specialization

is the lack of "partial template specialization" for functions actually a shortcoming? When I define a template, along with an overload to act as a specialization, it always seems to work.

```
template<typename T>
static T Func(T a) { std::cout << "a"; return a; }
static long Func(long a) { std::cout << "b"; return a; }
```

As in, it does not conflict with `Func<long>` in terms of inference. i.e. `Func(22l);` invokes the correct function and without ambiguity.

Isn't this just as good as template specialization for functions? Are there pitfalls with exposing such functions that I need to watch out for?

Edit: I see one difference is `Func<long>` can't possibly invoke the overload, so inference is REQUIRED here... definitely one potential source of confusion, especially if referencing it from another template.

Another edit: As pointed out, this is a full specialization, not a partial one. Luckily it seems to still work with partial:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
static U Func(T a, U b) { std::cout << "a"; return a; }
template<typename T>
static long Func(T a, long b) { std::cout << "b"; return a; }

Func<long>(12, 22);  // invokes template
Func<long>(12, 22l); // invokes "specialization"
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a suitable example. Shouldn't the second function also be a template? Albeit with fewer parameters? i.e. the current example is more akin to *full* specialization than to *partial* specialization.

Comment: Thanks, I updated with a better example. It seems to work in the simple case, although this does open the door to a lot of possibilities I might not have thought of yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

```
template<class R, class T>
R convert(const T&);
```

Suppose that we want to do something special for `convert<void>(/*something*/)` (i.e., the case where `R` is `void`). You can't do it with simple overloading or full specializations. (The usual trick is to delegate to a static member function of a helper class template, which can be partially specialized.)

Comment: It actually seems like it works to me (VS2013). `template<class R, class T>
R convert(const T& a) { std::cout << "a" ; }
template<class R>
R convert(const long& a) { std::cout << "b" ; }` and then `convert<void>(12)` and `convert<void>(12l)` call a and b, respectively. EDIT: nevermind, I think you meant pivoting on the void.

Comment: Yeah I agree, we are limited to inference, so we can't specialize off a return value using overloading.

Comment: I think I can write two overloads of `convert` that do what you want via SFINAE.  Of course, that is using a jackhammer to kill an ant, but if it needs killing...

Comment: @Yakk I said *simple* overloading. *simple*. ;) (And it will quickly grow into an gigantic mess if we want to add more "specializations"...)